# Most common React mistakes

Tags: reactjs

I am planning a small React meetup with some colleagues and friends next week. Although we are all relatively new to React, we know the basic concepts, syntax, etc. Let us say, we are past the "Hello World" and are messing around with our "ToDoApp" :) We may soon be getting started on some real projects and are preparing for it.

I have titled the workshop "Avoiding Common React Traps" and the following are what I plan to share with my colleagues:

- Managing state

  - Do not mutate the state directly
  - `setState` is asynchronous
  - Deep merging the state
  - Finding the right "home" for your state!
- Props

  - Missing to pass props when passing props to deep children
  - Difference between `this.props` and `props`
- Controlled components- getting it right takes some practice
- `bind`ing your callbacks (or use arrows)
- Routing

  - Passing `props` to `Route`
  - Nested `Route`
- Writing logic inside `render()`, especially, do not `setState()` or `callAPI()`

Would appreciate items I could add to this list. Thanks in advance!! :)

Comment: Using HOC components instead of inheritance.

Comment: Don't setState in `render()` or in `componentDidUpdate()`.

Comment: @earthling You mean, it is recommended or not recommended?

Comment: Using data-relevant keys for arrays (indices are not always suitable when the order or the identity of array items can be changed)

Comment: It's better to use HOC. Inheritance in react is asking for trouble

Comment: React component lifecycle

Comment: I think this is too broad and/or opinion based.

Comment: Always set a key on iterated items.

Comment: Differences between presentational and container components

Comment: You know I am tired of people saying something is opinion-based. It's useful to the community and that should be enough. Almost everything is opinion-based.

Comment: Use functional components when you can - ie doesn't require instance methods, state, or refs.

Comment: Try to break down and re-use components as much as possible. It's easy to write bloated components when you first start using react.

Comment: [Using a function in `setState` instead of an object](https://medium.com/@shopsifter/using-a-function-in-setstate-instead-of-an-object-1f5cfd6e55d1)

Comment: Don't change the DOM directly using jQuery or DOM apis.

Comment: @OriDrori How did I miss that!

Comment: If you really really really really (!) have to change the DOM directly (for instance, not finding a suitable react library or the dom element being outside your react app), do your dom operations in componentDidMount and make sure you clean up in componentWillUnmount and also ensure you return false in shouldComponentUpdate